# Change tab via Collapsing Toolbar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tabs, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have a collapsing toolbar that contains an image and a tab layout. When I swipe left/right over the image, the tabs don't change. Is it possible to control the tabs this way. Google Play Games and the Newsstand app does this.

Answer (score 0):

I think the code where is below may help you.

```
pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    pager.setAdapter(new MainTabsAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabs));
    pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(pager);
    tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_SCROLLABLE);
```

And then fill the tabs like;

```
tabs.add(item);
```